# 40 days before the formation of the fetus

Tags: marriage, agada-stories-legends, chazal, shidduchim

I know chazel say 40 days before the formation of a fetus a bas Kol goes out and says "bas ploni lploni" I was wondering in the language of the bas Kol, why does it say "**bas** ploni lploni" and not "bas ploni l ben ploni" or "ploni l plonis"?

Comment: Statistically she doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Because a daughter is the product of her home more than a son who goes out to learn

Comment: @Chatzkel sons traditionally learn directly from their fathers

Comment: I think it may be at conception, not before. in other words, 40 days before it's considered formed which takes 40 days

Comment: @shmosel neither does the man because it’s arbo’im yom kodem yetzias haholad, 40 days BEFORE conception

Comment: It's an insightful question, but let's clarify the issue here. If it would be "ploni lplonis", why would that be? Why is there a match predestined before birth? If the answer is simply "because that's the way Hashem wanted it",  then why can't males be matched to the daughters of other males, without necessarily picking a specific one? What would be the problem with that, from a Torah-value point of view (i.e. modern egalitarian values not included)?

Answer (score 5):

The [Ben Yehoyada](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Sotah.2a.3) (והנה מקשים) asks this and offers four answers:

1. The masculine is related to *rachamim* (compassion) and the feminine to *din* (severity). This enables evil forces to more easily attach themselves to a female. To avoid drawing negative attention to her, she isn't directly named.
2. Unlike the male, the female is initially under the control of her father, which is why only he can marry her off. Therefore she's identified with his name.
3. (Humorously) It's the girl's father who has to provide her wedding expenses and dowry, whereas the boy offers nothing from his side; if anything, he is also reliant on her dowry to set them up. Therefore her father gets the credit.
4. It wouldn't be appropriate for a heavenly voice to mention a female by name, so it uses her father's name.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Deleting my other comment.